# Get the first character from the filename in a filepath

Tags: c#, .net, linq, directory, filepath

I have an array of filepaths in a directory and I'm trying to move certain files based on alphabet.

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\user\desktop\folder", "*.txt");
foreach (var file in filePaths)
{
    if (file.StartsWith("A"))
    {
        //Move file
```

The obvious problem is that file.StartWith is pulling the entire filepath (*C:\user\desktop\folder\Albert.txt*) Which doesn't start with 'A'

So what would be the best way to just target the start of the actual file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See whether the [Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path) class can help.

Comment: @Jimi in what way?

Comment: Something like `filePaths.Where(file=>Path.GetFileName(file).StartsWith("A"))` should do the trick.

Comment: `if (Path.GetFileName(file).StartsWith("A")) {...}`

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with Path.GetFileName as per the suggestion by @Jimi

Answer (score 0):

What about this code

```cs
var dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\user\desktop\folder");
var files = dir.GetFiles();
foreach (var file in files)
{
    if(file.Name.StartsWith("A"))
    {
        //Move file
```

Answer (score 0):

You say you're looking to move files by alphabet- if you mean to put files into a folder whose name is the same as the first char of the filename then perhaps:

```
var desktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop); //don't hard code the path to the desktop
var root = Path.Combine(desktop, "foldernamehere"); //use path.combine to build paths
foreach(var f in directory.EnumerateFiles(root, "*.txt")){ //prefer EnumerateFiles over GetFiles
  var filename = Path.GetFileName(f);
  var dest = Path.Combine(root, filename.Remove(1));
  Directory.CreateDirectory(dest); //safe to call even if exists, ensures exists
  File.Move(f, Path.Combine(dest, filename));
}
```

See comments for more info

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string that represents a full filename (or directory name), and you want the name without the directory, consider to use [Path.GetFileName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilename?view=net-5.0)

```
string fullFileName = "C:\user\desktop\folder\Albert.txt";
string fileName = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullFileName);
```

fileName will be "Albert.txt"

With this in mind, your query will be easy:

```
IEnumerable<string> fullFileNames = ...
char startChar = 'A';
IEnumerable<string> fileNamesThatStartWithStartChar = fullFileNames
    .Where(fileName => Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName).StartsWitch(startChar));
```

In words: from every fileName in the sequence of fullFileName, take the fileName without the directory information. Keep the fileName if this "fileName without directory information" starts with the startChar.

Note: `StartsWitch(char)` is case sensitive. If you want to check case insensitive, use `String.StartsWitch(string, stringComparison)`

### There's room for improvement!

If you think that there might be a chance that you won't be using all information of all files, consider to use [Directory.EnymerateFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles) instead of GetFiles. This way, if at the end of your LINQ you decide to use only 3 of the fetched files (or worse: `FirstOrDefault()`, or `Any()`), you  won't have fetched all files.